# Is it possible to register custom helpers in Ghost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, ghost

I am using Ghost as an npm module following [this guide](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Using-Ghost-as-an-npm-module).

I would like to add some custom helpers that I can leverage inside of my themes. Is there a way to do this without changing code inside the Ghost module?

This is my current code:

```
const ghost = require('ghost');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-hbs');

const config = path.join(__dirname, 'config.js');
const coreHelpers = {};

coreHelpers.sd_nls  = require('./sd_nls');

// Register a handlebars helper for themes
function registerThemeHelper(name, fn) {
  hbs.registerHelper(name, fn);
}

registerThemeHelper('sd_nls', coreHelpers.sd_nls);

ghost({ config: config })
  .then(ghostServer => ghostServer.start());
```

I think one possible problem is that my `hbs` is a new handlebars instance, not the same one used by Ghost, therefore when Ghost runs it doesn't include any helpers I've registered.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately even with the most recent version this still is a very recent issue. I tried to come up with my own 3-file-based solution that will take the original Ghost Dockerfile and build from there adding custom helpers from just one directory.

Find it here:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/activenode/ghost-docker-custom-helpers
- https://github.com/activenode/ghost-docker-custom-helpers